# Datepicker vs dropdown list of dates for returning a list of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm new to this so I apologize for my stupidity in advance.

I'm working on a project site and would like to add a feature where users can select a date and get a list of events happening on that date. Would datepicker with a submit button be the best (easiest) way to do that, or would it be better to have them select a date from a dropdown which would then populate a second dropdown containing the events. This is a travel site, for some context. If both methods use the same AJAX/JSON magic to get the list and it doesn't matter, see my advance apology above.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend jQuery's datepicker. It's remarkably simple:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
</script>
```